# How to rewrite directories into query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Yay, my first Stackoverflow question ever! Been around for years but this one gets me.

I have an URL:
https://example.com/site.com/phpBB3/general-f1/things-are-getting-crazy-here-t948-60.html

(I need to test this locally first which is why I have set it this way)

I want to change the URL into:
https://example.com/site.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=948&start=60

I have my .htaccess file in /example.com/.htaccess and the content is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)\/([a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 [QSA,NE,L,NC]
```

I have AllowOverRide set and the rewrite mod is enabled.

This seems to work in https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
but not at the actual site. I'm going crazy. What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to solve my problem https://techtitbits.com/2008/10/phpbb-redirect-broken-links-after-uninstalling-an-seo-mod/